# What is Diameter of a Binary Tree? Is it Necessary that longest path for Diameter to go through the Root Node or not?

Tags: data-structures, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

The diameter of a tree T is the largest of the following quantities:

- the diameter of T’s left subtree
- the diameter of T’s right subtree
- the longest path between leaves that goes through the root of T (this can be computed from the heights of the subtrees of T).
  I don't want the Code but just want to know what is right?

Please Check the Link

[image: Both are right or Only Left One]

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not necessary for diameter of a binary tree to pass through its root element (e.g: when the binary tree is unbalanced).

Lets get this:

> Leaves of binary tree: nodes which have no chidren
>   Path: alternating set of nodes and edges which connect two paths.

In simpler terms (not exact definition) the diameter is longest path between any 2 leaf nodes in binary tree.

Inferred from: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/diameter-of-a-binary-tree/

Comment: the longest path between leaves that goes through the root of T?
what is the meaning of this point then.
i already check that ,above three points are copied from their ?

Comment: consider the left skew tree but the leave node contain two child then what is the diameter of that tree

Comment: @MayurRaikwar Ieaf node is the bottom most node in binary tree (the definition is it does not contain and children)

Comment: As per the Solution on Geeks they are calculating the diameter of left sub tree +diameter of right subtree + 1(root). then its a wrong solution because as per the Definition: "diameter is longest path between any 2 leaf nodes" then those 2 leaf node can exists only in left side or right side only

Comment: The solution on geeks is calculating the height (not diameter) of left sub-tree and height (not diameter) of right sub-tree + 1 (root), this gives the length of path through root. The diameter (optimized solution) is calculated as max(lh + rh + 1, max(ldiameter, rdiameter))

Answer (score 0):

The diameter of a graph G, denoted ***diam G***, is the length of the longest shortest path between two nodes in the graph. Stated differently, diam G is the maximum distance between any two nodes in a graph, assuming you measure distances by taking shortest paths between nodes.

In the context of a tree, where there is only one path between any two nodes, the diameter of a tree is the maximum length of any path in that tree, assuming we’re allowed to either move up or down edges.

As the examples above show, the longest path in a tree does not necessarily need to pass through the root of the tree. However, we can say the following about the longest path:

- If it does pass through the root of the tree, then that path would be formed by taking the longest path from the root down the left subtree and gluing it to the longest path from the root down to the right subtree.
- If it doesn’t, then it’s purely in the left subtree or purely in the right subtree.

This is the basis for algorithms that compute the diameter of a binary tree. The first case can be computed by recursively determining the heights of the left and right subtree, which can be used to determine the lengths of the longest paths within those trees. The second case can be computed by recursively determining the diameters of the two subtrees. By folding these into a single recursive function that returns both the height of the tree and its diameter, you can compute tree diameters in time O(n).